# Search an entire Google Sheet for a value and return true/false

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, search

I need to search every sheet in a Google sheet for a value - currency - and return true if it's found. The code below is returning false for everything

```
function searchForNumber(value) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var searchString = value;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      if (typeof data[i][j] === searchString) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It seems like this post could benefit from more specific information. It would be helpful to include details about the code being used, as well as a clear explanation of how Google Sheets and Google Apps Script are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`TextFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) class, like this:

```
function searchForNumber(value) {
  return !!SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createTextFinder(String(value))
    .findNext();
}
```

To get the search string from a spreadsheet cell in the format it appears in the spreadsheet, use `Range.getDisplayValue()`.

If necessary, add [`.matchEntireCell(true)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchEntireCell(Boolean)), [`.matchCase(true)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchcasematchcase) and so on, per your requirements.

Comment: This is great - thanks - but the list of strings that I'm searching for are in the spreadsheet - so it is always returning true.

Can I exclude the active sheet from TextFinder?

Comment: That is a different question that will require a different solution. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.